# Automatically generate symbolic name for enum values in clang compiler

Tags: string, enums, clang, maps

In C/C++, when an enumerator is defined, automatically generate a map of the symbolic names corresponding to the enum values.

For example, given the following enumerator:

enum Day {

```
Monday,

Tuesday,

Wednesday,

Thursday,

Friday,

Saturday,

Sunday
```

};

A table of string names, derived from the enum values, should be generated automatically, such as:

const char *__nameof_Day[] = {

```
"Monday",

"Tuesday",

"Wednesday",

"Thursday",

"Friday",

"Saturday",

"Sunday"
```

};

The above should be generated in Clang such that it is emitted as a compiler generated variable into the object file. As a result, searching through the symbols within the generated object file should show up the above symbol.

The same should work for enum class and enum struct (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum) as well.

The variable name for the table of symbolic names should be derived from the original enum.

I tried creating a vector in enumdecl class and storing the names in it.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! This is a site where you can post
questions about your programming problems. You have posted a problem
but you have not asked any question about it. Please read 
[How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)